# How to interpret bulk API processing times

Tags: trigger, rest-api, batch, bulk-api, bulk-api-v2

According to the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_reference_batchinfo.htm)

- `apexProcessingTime` is `The number of milliseconds taken to process triggers and other processes related to the job data`
- `apiActiveProcessingTime` is `The number of milliseconds taken to actively process the job and includes apexProcessingTime, but doesn't include the time the job waited in the queue to be processed or the time required for serialization and deserialization. This is the sum of the equivalent times in all batches in the job`
- `totalProcessingTime` is `The number of milliseconds taken to process the job. This is the sum of the total processing times for all batches in the job`

Below is a sample response of job info with a batch size of 6k. (Should be only one batch on Salesforce side as each batch is of size 10k).

`Job Info: (apexProcessingTime=7097309, apiActiveProcessingTime=844852, retries=1, totalProcessingTime=261318, numberRecordsProcessed=6000, numberRecordsFailed=10)`

Issues:

`apexProcessingTime` (118 min) is much greater than `apiActiveProcessingTime` (14 min) and `totalProcessingTime` has the least value (4 min).

I use the previous batch information to figure out how long to wait for the next batch. The response from job info does not seem to fit the definition of the docs.

How should this be interpreted? Have also observed scenarios where `totalProcessingTime` was returned as 34 ms, which is clearly too good to be true!